# Swift variable syntax

Tags: swift

Sorry for asking a stupid question. But I am confused about this:

```
var debugMessage: String {
    return "Level 1"
}
```

Does that code mean the same as:

```
var debugMessage: String = "Level 1"
```

Or is it a closure?

Comment: In short: the result is the same. Btw, you could also do `var debugMessage = { return "Lebel 1" }`

Answer (score 1):

The first:

```
var debugMessage: String {
    return "Level 1"
}
```

is a short form of

```
var debugMessage: String {
    get { return "Level 1" }
}
```

which is a computed property declaration with only a getter.

And the second is just a simple stored property declaration with an initialisation.

As you can see, one is a computed property and the other is a stored property. So their differences are mostly the same as the differences between computed properties and stored properties.

Here are a few of them.

- Computed properties with only a getter cannot be set. Stored properties declared with `var` can be set
- Computed properties can be placed in extensions. Stored properties cannot.
- Computed properties doesn't actually occupy memory ("Level 1" isn't stored in memory) until you access it. Stored properties will have their values put into memory when the object is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

The first example you provided is a **computed variable**. If it always returns `Level 1`, then the two examples produce **the same result**.

However, generally speaking, the second method only provides an i**nitial value** to the variable, while a computed variable can **change** it's return value.